# simple_form select-field turns into input-field after validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm using simple_form combined with twitter boostrap for my rails application. And I've one problem that stops me.

```
<%= f.input :title %>
<%= f.input :url %>
<%= f.input :tag_list, :label => 'Tags' %>
<%= f.input :type_id, :collection => @types, :label_method => :type_name, :value_method => :id, :include_blank => false %>
<%= f.input :description %>
```

That creates me nice form. But when the validation fails every input-field shows their error.
But not the select field, it only changes from a select-field into a normal input-field filled with the id and I don't know why.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For some reasons, it seems Rails + Bootstrap + Simple_form keep you select field after validation when the collection is placed into the field itself instead of your controller's action. This should work :

```
<%= f.input :title %>
<%= f.input :url %>
<%= f.input :tag_list, :label => 'Tags' %>
<%= f.input :type_id, :collection => Type.all.order('type_name'), :label_method => :type_name, :value_method => :id, :include_blank => false %>
<%= f.input :description %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Weird bug, just faced it myself and had to use this solution. Thanks anyway! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well I would need more information to help you out. 
Could you post your models? or explain what `@types` is and what it is for.

**This is a basic simple for association:**

*models/type.rb*
`belongs_to :post`

*models/post.rb*
`has_many :types`

*views/post/_form.html.haml*
`= f.association :types`

Make sure you have a column named "title" or "name" for types.

Comment: okay this form is for creating a bookmark and type decripes the bookmark-type like blog-article or forum-post.
and the association is:
type.rb 'has_many :bookmarks'
bookmark.rb 'belongs_to :type'

Comment: did you try `= f.association :types` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set **@types** in methods **create** or **update** before render action **new** or **edit** respectively

For example

```
def new
  @your_object = YourObject.new
  @types = Type.all
  ....
end

def create
    @your_object = YourObject.new(your_object_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @your_object.save
        format.html { redirect_to ... }
        format.json { render action: 'show' ... }
      else
        ### ! init data for the form ! ###
        @types = Type.all
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: ... }
      end
    end
end
```